# Avoid server call on HTML Object style display property change

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, object

What should be done to avoid a server request for the pdf? I have tried `visibility=hidden` and `width=0`.

```
<object class='pdfClass' data='"+conventionId+"/showPdf.html' width='100%' height='600'></object>

function toggleConv() {
    if (...) {
        document.getElementById(conventionId).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(conventionId).style.display = ''; //causes a refresh
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After testing, I found out that the following works in Firefox 13 without reloading:

```
<object id="test" class='pdfClass' data='https://web3.unt.edu/riskman/PDF/Guidelines_on_Staphylococcal_Infections-Athletics__Revised__06-22-06.pdf' width='100%' height='600'></object>

function toggleConv(o){
    var test = document.getElementById('test');

    if (o == true){
        test.style.width = 0;
        test.style.height = 0;
    } else {
        test.style.width = '100%';
        test.style.height = '600px';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KnEYC/2/

---

*Original response.* Note that the `height` and `width` of the element also need to be toggled down to little or nothing to prevent it continuing to taking up the same space.

One technique would be to hide it from view by placing it way off screen:

```
#test {
    position: relative;
}

function toggleConv(o){
    if (o == true){
        document.getElementById('test').style.left = '-10000px';
        document.getElementById('test').style.top = '-10000px';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('test').style.left = '';
        document.getElementById('test').style.top = '';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/KnEYC/

Comment: I tried both the ways, without any luck, the pdf stays there. This object tag is being generated dynamically, would that be an issue?

Comment: Originally this was to be done with Jquery, but toggle() causes a reload hence I went with plain JS, any idea if we can suppress the reload with Jquery methods ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the HTML, it'll load. The only real way, as far as I know, to prevent a request, is to dynamically add the url for the object (or even add the object itself) in your code:

```
if (...) {
    // Add the data tag here
}
```

Comment: As I replied to Jared, the object tag is being generated dynamically, its data source is picked up based on response variables. Is it possible to get those variables in this JavaScript ?